# Prefill values associated to current_user in Backbone template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm trying to achieve something like this;
A user is able to create a subuser in a Backbone generated form, the user should be able to choose items associated with the current_user to be associated to the new user.
How would I get this values to the template and how would I access the current_user?

I'm using Rails and Backbone. Any resources on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a JSON representation of the user in a javascript snippet somewhere in the view. Then, in backbone just use window.current_user. *You should also customize what is in the json of a user object for functional and security reasons.*

```
window.current_user = <%= current_user.to_json %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what would be the best way to have the associated items from the current_user in my new user view? For example; The user should be able to choose from a list of checkboxes containing current_user.cars to be associated with the new user. How would I get the available cars to the newUser view(and template). Is the best approach to set something like window.current_user { cars: <%= current_user.cars.to_json %> ?